# How can I convert a string like "10.000,50" to float number 10000.50 in robotframework

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, robotframework

How can I convert a string like `10.000,50` to float number `10000.50` in robotframework

I try this

```
ParseFloat
    [Arguments]    ${String}
    Execute JavaScript    parseFloat(${String})

Replace
    [Arguments]    ${str}
    Execute JavaScript    ("" +${str}).replace(/\\./g, "").replace(/,/g, ".")
```

But didn't got the result that I expected

Comment: What result did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript you can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove all the `.` and than replace the only `,` by a dot. Finally return the [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) value:

```js
String.prototype.toFloat = function() {
  var n = +this.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.');
  return n.toFixed(2);
}

var n = '10.000,50'.toFloat();
console.log(n);
```

Note: that `String.prototype.toFloat()` function can return `NaN` if the string is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` characters and replace `,` with `.`. `parseFloat` and your done.

```js
function strToFloat(str) {
  return parseFloat(str.replace(/\./ig,'').replace(/,/ig,'.'))
}
console.log(strToFloat("10.000,50"))
```